# soap client calling function with parameters and type

Tags: php, xml, soap-client

I have soap request with body

```
<soap:Body>
    <ProcessRequest>
        <request xsi:type="GetNotification">
            <node1>val1</node2>
            <node2>val2</node2>
        </request>
    </ProcessRequest>
</soap:Body>
```

I am trying to pass request **type** **GetNotification** in soap client call in PHP but its not working.
in $args I am passing

```
$args = ['node1' => 'val1','node2'=>'node2'];
$response = $client->ProcessRequest(['request'=>$args])
```

how do i pass **type** **GetNotification**

Comment: highly recommend you don't use php's SoapClient it's buggy as hell

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tool:

> https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator

You can give it the soap url and it will generate full list of classes for the service.
Using these classes it will be much easier to understand what and how you need to send you request.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be something like this. Because the  xsi:type indicates that request value should be GetNotification. Keep in mind that i didn't test it and it's just a thought.

```php
<?php 

//using arrays
$response = $client->ProcessRequest(['request' => [
    'GetNotification' => ['node1' => 'val1', 'node2' => 'val2']
]);

//using objects
class request 
{
    private $GetNotification;

    public function __construct(GetNotification $getNotification) 
    {
         $this->GetNotification = $getNotification;
    }
}

class GetNotification
{
    private $node1;
    private $node2;

    public function __construct(string $node1, string $node2) 
    {
         $this->node1 = $node1;
         $this->node2 = $node2;
    }
}

$response = $client->ProcessRequest(
    new request(new GetNotification('val1', 'val2'))
);
```